# Series representation of multiplication of two modified Bessel function

Tags: special-functions, power-series, bessel-functions

Series representation of multiplication of two Bessel function $J_{\mu}(az) J_{\nu}(bz)$ is in terms of sum of hypergeometric functions $_2F_1$, it given in book Treatise on Theory of Bessel Functions by Watson.

What is representation of multiplication of two modified Bessel function of different kinds

$I_{\mu}(az) K_{\nu}(bz) = ?$

Interesting to me is case of $\nu$ is an integer $n$.

Comment: $K_\nu$ is a linear sum of $I_\nu$ and $I_{-\nu}$, unless $\nu$ is integer. Since $I_\nu(x)/J_\nu(ix)=const$, this should be easy.

Comment: @Nemo What if $\nu$ is an integer?

Comment: I don't know, but I guess one will obtain a derivative of hypergeometric function with respect to a parameter, which will be a series involving generalized Harmonic numbers.